# Keycloak access_token forward from idp

Tags: keycloak

Is there a way to forward the original access_token from an Identity Provider? Or requesting this in a form of API request?

We need this to use with the IdP specific API.

Answer (score 1):

Map the data you need to the keycloak user, then you can forward this to the clients.

You can read more here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_mappers

Comment: Not working, I think this is only working for fields in the user_info!

Comment: I was able to map a "Hardcoded Attribute" for the "idp" and "picture" profile.